# info from database to txtfield and back

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying:
take info from my database to texfields (infinite database data so cant name fields in hardcore mode each by each), then change data and put it back to database.

Problem: 
Can't name my textfields in order to check if data was changed.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Data</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>



<?php 

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$base = 'CREATE DATABASE itemsbase';
$select = mysql_select_db("itemsbase",$conn);
$table_items = 'CREATE TABLE `items` (
   `items_id` int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   `shop_id` int,
   `itemname` varchar(40),
   `price` varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(items_id))';
$query = "SELECT * FROM items";
$result = mysql_query($query);  

if(!$select){ 
if(mysql_query($base, $conn)){
echo "base created";
}else{
echo 'error: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}}


if(mysql_query($table_items, $conn)){
echo "table created";
}else{
echo 'error: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}


echo "<form method='post'><table>"; 
echo "<tr><td>" . 'item id' . "</td><td>" . 'shop id' . "</td><td>" . 'item name' . "</td><td>" . 'price' . "</td></tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='itemid" . $row[1] . "' value='" . $row['items_id'] . "'></td><td><input type='text' name='shop_id" . $row[1] . "' value='" . $row['shop_id'] . "'></td><td><input type='text' name='itemname" . $row[1] . "' value='" . $row['itemname'] . "'></td><td><input type='text' name='price" . $row[1] . "' value='" . $row['price'] . "'></td></tr>";

//and here trying take info from field and check if it mach with info in database


$fieldinfo = $_POST['itemid' . $row[1]];

if($fieldinfo=$row['items_id']){
}else{
$row['items_id']=$fieldinfo;}

//but facing error undefined index
}

echo "</table></form>"; 



mysql_close ();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may help to add some of the comment descriptions to your Problem: description.

Answer (score 0):

name the text field as an array with the record ID so you will be able to relate that back to the data base.

```
<input type='text' name='item[<?=$row['id']?>]'   value='<?=$row['value']'>
```

or you can add a custom attribute to the text feild with the table record ID.

```
<input type='text' name='item' rowid='<?=$row['id']?>'   value='<?=$row['value']?>'>
```

either way can be reference by jquery to check for update and update database.